# Intuition behind Einstein and Mobius addition and scalar multiplication

Tags: differential-geometry, intuition

Im recently studying gyrogroups and gyrovector spaces and I come across his definition to the Einstein addition and the scalar multiplication that makes the unit disk $\mathbb D$ a gyrovector spaces defined by :

**Definition :**
Let $\mathbb{V}$ a real inner product space and let $\mathbb V_s$ the $s-$ball of $\mathbb V$, where $s>0$. The Einstein addition is given by $${u} \oplus_{{E}} {v}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{{u} \cdot {v}}{s^{2}}}\left\{{u}+{v}+\frac{1}{s^{2}} \frac{\gamma_{{u}}}{1+\gamma_{{u}}}(u.v).u\right\}$$
for all $u,v\in \mathbb V_s $, where  $$
\gamma_{{v}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{\|v\|^{2}}{s^{2}} }},
$$
**Definition :**  Let $\left(\mathbb{V}_{s}, \oplus_{E}\right)$ be an Einstein gyrogroup. The Einstein scalar multiplication $r \otimes_{E} {v}={v} \otimes_{E} r$ in $\mathbb{V}_{s}$ is given by the equation
$$
r \otimes_{E} {v}=s \frac{(1+\|{v}\| / s)^{r}-(1-\|{v}\| / s)^{r}}{(1+\|{v}\| / s)^{r}+(1-\|{v}\| / s)^{r}} \frac{{v}}{\|{v}\|}=s \tanh \left(r \tanh ^{-1} \frac{\|{v}\|}{s}\right) \frac{{v}}{\|{v}\|},
$$
where $r \in \mathbb{R}, {v} \in \mathbb{V}_{s}, {v} \neq {0}$; and $r \otimes_{E} {0}={0}$.

---

The problem is that I cant see the intuition behind these definitions ? Why they are defined like that ? The same work is done with the Mobius gyrogroups and gyrovector spaces ?  Any help is really appreciated !

Comment: Just to get more context, are you already familiar with, say, Lorentz boosts in special relativity? Did you have any thoughts about that/the context in which you're encountering this stuff?

Comment: I am not familiar with it but I am encountering these in a book of Abraham Ungar entitled "A gyrovector space approach to hyperbolic geometry"

Comment: The goal is to found some formulas of geodesics and barycentre of a triangle in the Poincaré and Klein disk

Comment: The approach that Ungar was studyied was good but I din't understand how he get all this formulas, and I am trying to found some results of geodesics and triangles but without using these notations

Comment: The motivation would be special relativity but I'm not sure there is an intuitive way to explain it since it's rather famously counter-intuitive.